# For variables in document (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, iteration

This code isn't completely finished yet. I'm trying to iterate over all 'm' variables within a page until there are no more 'm's within the page. Right now I have 'for (m in document)', which I know to be wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction for the correct syntax?

```
var m = document.getElementsByClassName('project')
  var n = document.getElementsByClassName('web')
  var o = document.getElementsByClassName('print')
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName('illustration')

function projectFilter(type){
     if (type === 'print'){
      for (m in document){
        if (getElementsByClassName('print') != null){
          m.style(opacity=0.3)
          console.log("Whatshappening")
      }
   }
   if (type === 'web'){
      console.log('webbyshit')
   }
   if (type === 'illustration'){
      console.log('illustrating')
   }
   if (type === 'project'){
      console.log('EVERYTHING')
   }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You already have `m` defined at the top of your script, so you don't have to look for it `in document`. Just loop it like you would loop an array (`m` is a `NodeList` object, but it has a `length` property like arrays do):

```
for(var i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
    // do something with each m[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Three problems

- you are iterating incorrectly
- your style assignment is incorrect:
- `getElementsByClassName` will always return an object, even if it is an empty set.  Check its length property to see if you get any elements back.

```
for (var i = 0, len = m.length; i<len; i++) {
    if (m[i].getElementsByClassName('print').length > 0 ){
        m.style.opacity=0.3;
    }
}
```